# How Windows (or other OSes) update client's background area?

Tags: windows, algorithm, drawing, custom-component

Or to ask it another way, how OnEraseBkgnd() works?

I'm building a custom control and I hit on this problem.
 Childs are rectangles, as usual. I had to *disable* OnEraseBkgnd() and I use only the OnPaint().
 What I need is to **efficiently clear the area behind the childs** and without flickering.
 Techniques like using *back buffers* are not an option.

**Edit**: I am very interested in the algorithm that's under the hood of OnEraseBkgnd(). But any helpful answer will also be accepted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is double buffering not an option?

Comment: (1) I use *normal* windows, (2) there is a possibility to use it also in hand held devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in Windows, the easiest (but not most effective) means of reducing flicker, is to turn off the `WM_ERASEBKGND` notification handling. This is because if you erase the background in the notification handler, then paint the window in the `WM_PAINT` handler, there is a short delay between the two - this delay is seen as a flicker.

Instead, if you do all of the erasing and drawing in the `WM_PAINT` handler, you will tend to see a lot less flicker. This is because the delay between the two is reduced. You will still see some flicker, especially when resizing because there is still a small delay between the two actions, and you cannot always get in all of the drawing before the next occurance of the vertical blanking interrupt for the monitor. If you cannot use double buffering, then this is probably the most effective method you will be able to use.

You can get better drawing performance by following most of the usual recommendations around client area invalidation - do not invalidate the whole window unless you really need to. Try to invalidate only the areas that have changed. Also, you should use the `BeginDeferWindowPos` functions if you are updating the positions of a collection of child windows at the same time.